# How to trigger a function on all images with a class when done loading in JQuery 3.X?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage on which a lot of images need to load. I want to show a div with a loading gif while the image is loading, but I want to fade out that div when the image is done loading. When I was searching the internet I found the ".load" function, but that's not working on the images. The ".on('load', function(){...})" doesn't work either.

This is what I tried, but doesn't work.

```html
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="image1.jpg">

  <img src="thumbs/image1.jpg" class="slideshow_image"/>
  
  <div class="loading">
    <div class="loading_image">
      <img src="loading.gif"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</a>

<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="image2.jpg">

  <img src="thumbs/image2.jpg" class="slideshow_image"/>
  
  <div class="loading">
    <div class="loading_image">
      <img src="loading.gif"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</a>

<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="image3.jpg">

  <img src="thumbs/image3.jpg" class="slideshow_image"/>
  
  <div class="loading">
    <div class="loading_image">
      <img src="loading.gif"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".slideshow_image").on("load", function() {
      $(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any console errors?  Also where are you executing that load binding in relation to the markup on the page?  And I also do not see a jQuery include in your question.

Comment: @Taplar, I linked JQuery via a CDN link, but I didn't include that in the code above. I'm executing that load in a <script> in HTML, for testing. I tested the JQuery link in my script, so I know that works. I edited the code snippet, so the relation to the markup is clear.

Comment: @Taplar, Also, I get no console errors when executing

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working fine.

https://codepen.io/tmdesigned/pen/NWqqXwy

Probably what you are experience is conflict with the gallery library you are using. They often duplicate images in the HTML to achieve their effects. I'd suggests looking at the final output in your inspector and see if the `.next()` logic still holds.

But, to answer your question if you remove that gallery, as I did in the link above, you'll see the 'loading' image fade out (in the example, all 6 images--3 display images, 3 loading images--are the same, but you can still see the effect).

```
<script>
    $(".slideshow_image").on("load", function() {
      $(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. I had another script placed before my custom script that only executed when the page was fully loaded. So obviously my custom code didn't run before that other script was finished running, and that was only gonna happen when the page (and all images) were fully loaded. So I placed this custom script before the other script, and now it works just fine. Thank you!